# No consigo encontrar la solución para este problema en Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: Aqui el enunciado del ejercicio]Al no saber n veo que tenemos 4 variables se que de alguna manera el no saber n no tiene relevancia real ya que no es más que una matriz para los n intentos hasta conseguir la solución (o eso pienso) alguien me podría ayudar con el codigo del ejercicio ? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se te puede ayudar si mostrás lo que has intentado y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: n es el índice, NR es un método iterativo, lo que significa que uno parte de una condición inicial y calcula aproximaciones sucesivas de la solución si X=[x,y,z];  X_1 seria la aproximación calculada con la condición inicial X_0. Lo único que tenes que hacer es crear una función o expresión que te permita evaluar la función y el jacobiano y luego hacer la cuenta. Tenés todos los datos. Qué intentaste?